# Burninate request for tag [angular-material-7]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

This tag is very misleading because Angular Material is currently on version 2, not 7, and there is enough confusing about Angular versions out there already.

I see that the user who created the tag made some effort trying to clarify the reasons for creating this tag, but I firmly believe that this tag should have never been created.

Tag: [angular-material-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material-7)

Reference: https://github.com/angular/material2

To my point, I still believe that the tag should be [angular-material2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material2) and [angular7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular7) or in the worst case scenario [angular-material2-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material2-7), because it is using material2.

Comment: and you also have [angular-material-5] and  [angular-material-6], I do agree with you this is incorrect tagging the correct tagging would be [angular], then version es. [angular7] and finally [angular-material]. If you know the person creating these you can ping them in comments (link to this meta) so they can explain the reason for these tags.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Angular Material *is* on version 7.

Comment: @EJoshuaS:  Make up your mind - either the question is off-topic, or it has an answer.  You can't like, have your cake and eat it too, you know...

Comment: Just FYI, the Git repository you link to has the version explicitly listed in the readme as 7.x.x (well, not the Xs but you get my point), which kind of invalidates your own point.

Comment: @Makoto It does have an answer - it's just that the issue effectively can't be reproduced because the library *is*, in fact, on version 7.

Comment: The inability of the Angular development team to comprehend version numbers strikes again. We have enough problems with our own tagging system. We don't need any help from badly-versioned software. C'mon guys!

Comment: @CodyGray to understand this, it is important to know that [angular-materials] is a component library built with angular (It follows same major version number), hence if you are using angular7 you will also use angular-materials7. I do agree angular tags on SO is a real mess (mostly due to the initial AngularJS problem) and personally I do not believe we need these subtags on material, instead we should encourage that OP adds the correct version tag of angular

Comment: *However this question needs to be rewritten to explain this and probably a synonym-request is enough, hence [angular-material-X] becomes synonym of [angular-material]*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an Angular expert, but I think that you're mistaken about the versioning. The [web site](https://material.angular.io/) lists Angular Material as being on version 7.3.1, *not* version 2.

Also, from [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_material7/index.htm):

> Angular Material 7 is a UI component library for Angular developers. Angular Material components help in constructing attractive, consistent, and functional web pages and web applications while adhering to modern web design principles like browser portability, device independence, and graceful degradation. It helps in creating faster, beautiful, and responsive websites. It is inspired by the Google Material Design.

There are numerous other resources available on this technology on the web. Since this appears to be a real thing, I don't think that we should burninate it.

Comment: I am an expert in Angular. Angular is in version 7: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md but material is in version 2: this is verion 1 https://github.com/angular/material and this is version 2 https://github.com/angular/material2 and this is why I think it is very important to burninate this tag and also other tags that are confusing.

Comment: @mruanova:  The *library* is probably called Material2, but the ***version*** is ***very much*** not at 2.

Comment: Ok, I see it here https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md version 7

Comment: To my point, I still believe that the tag should be angular-material2 and angular7 or in the worst case scenario angular-material2-7 because it is using material2

Comment: @mruanova In any case, the original premise of the burnination request (that there is no version 7) is demonstrably incorrect.

Comment: While you are correct related to version number, the tag is useless since the component library is built with angular (follows same major version), hence its useless we should instead encourage to add the version tag of angular [angular7]

Comment: @PetterFriberg Maybe so, but that doesn't change the fact that the premise of this request is demonstrably incorrect - there *is*, in fact, a version 7 of this software, so it can't be reproduced.

Comment: again I agree, but I do think this needs to be done, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380677/burninate-request-for-tag-angular-material-7/380679?noredirect=1#comment673722_380677

Comment: @Petter Looks like this question is about to be deleted. Probably best to post a new question with your recommendation. I would love to get some Angular experts together to clean up the Angular tags in a sensible way. I can't make the decisions on what is best. The only thing I know about "angular" relates to anatomy, not programming. But I can help carry out the community consensus.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for heads-up, I need sometime but will see if I can setup a post that atleast is a start on a clean up effort, using mostly synonyms and renaming to avoid too much community work

Comment: @CodyGray I have posted an [initial meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380756/what-should-our-naming-strategy-for-angular-related-libraries-be), trying to involve more then just angular community. Not sure if it can bring something but that is my attempt.