# What should our naming strategy for Angular-related libraries be?

Tags: discussion, tags

Yes, this is about the never ending [Angular](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=angular) madness, and I will briefly explain the fundamental issues of the naming problem (since it was not our fault). The objective with this is to get a broader community base (all our tagging experts) involved. If you already know about the mess, feel free to skip the introduction.

## Introduction

Google started to develop this framework with the name of "AngularJS" and with the release of "AngularJS 2" they actually presented a different frame work (architectural, language, expression syntax, etc). Fundamentally if you were searching for a solution in "AngularJS 2" a solution in "AngularJS" would not do you much good, but instead only increase your confusion.

Google soon realized that "JS" was not a good description, probably since with the new framework developers now used TypeScript to write the components?, they dropped the "JS", and it became "Angular 2".

*but but, now that we are developing Angular 2 version 3....*

Well, that's a mess so they dropped the 2 and the frameworks are now named [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and [Angular](https://angular.io/).

Stack Overflow finally [found peace](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341263/5292302) on the main tags, [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) and [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular). Additional to these tags developers can add version tags:

- [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) has [angularjs-1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-1.5), [angularjs-1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-1.6),[angularjs-1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-1.7) etc

  <sup>Let me smile some when considering what version they will invent after 1.9</sup>
- [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) has [angular5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular5),[angular6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular6),[angular7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular7), etc.

## Naming strategy for related libraries

I will give as example a few major with the intent to find a common strategy.

**angular-material**

This is a component library (datepickers, etc.) built with Angular that still suffers from the **2** issue. For AngularJS the official naming is [material](https://github.com/angular/material) and for Angular it is [material2](https://github.com/angular/material2), in fact we have [angularjs-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-material), [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material), [angular-material2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material2), [angular2-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-material) and then since now we are really confused [angular-material-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material-5), [angular-material-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material-6), etc. The version tags of material2 as I see it have no sense; it's probably just a side effect of the confusion (I'm using Angular7 not 2, not realizing that the library named material2 currently is in version 7 :)).

**angularfire**

The official binding for firebase, same problems as material, AngularJS version is [angularfire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire) and for Angular guess what? [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2), so we have [angularfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularfire), [angularfire2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularfire2), [angularfire5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularfire5)?? But not [angularjsfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjsfire).

**angular-bootstrap**

For AngularJS that would be [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and for Angular [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home). Ooh great they are named differently [angular-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-bootstrap), [angularjs-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-bootstrap), [ng-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-bootstrap), [angular-ui-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-bootstrap), and [bootstrap-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-ui).

## My considerations choosing different naming strategy.

1. Remove all reference in the tag to AngularJS or Angular, hence for example we would only keep [angular-material] and [angularfire]. The additional tag [angularjs] or [angular] will tell which one it is.

   - Update tag wikis to state that they need to add if `angular-js` or `angular`
   - We need to search and fix question that may *not* have the additional tag
   - Moderators will create synonyms to this single tag.
   - User can no more filter for example [angular-material2] they will need to add additional tag.
   - How do we handle if library have different name? as in bootstrap example?
2. Use *js* to indicate the difference, hence keep two tags [angularjs-material] and [angular-material],[angularjs-fire] and [angular-fire], [angularjs-bootstrap] and [ng-bootstrap].

   - We need to some extensive manual retagging since for example now the [angular-fire] is currently referenced to [angularjs]
   - Moderators will create synonyms to these two tags.
   - The name does not correspond with library name a diligent user may notice that they are using [angular-material2] not [angular-material] which can be confusing.
3. Keep the original library names [angular-material] and [angular-material2], [angularfire], and [angularfire2]. [angular-ui-bootstrap] and [ng-bootstrap].

   - Well, this is the correct name.
   - Users will continue with the confusion (I'm using version 7 of Angular, not 2 or add angular-material to an Angular question since they missed the 2 name), but we edit and try to create synonyms as we go.

This mess is [even deeper](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296857/burninate-73-angularjs-directive-tags) with tons of directive tags, etc., but for now let's start with a strategy for these libraries. After that maybe it's easier to find a strategy for those that are not burnations, but synonyms which is much more practical from a community perspective (one moderator click vs. 100 of hours of community users reviewing).

Comment: Me personally I think option 2 is too much rooted in the past and in the now, not so much the future. AngularJS usage will dwindle over time until it has lost most of it's relevance. I think whatever choice is made now, it should be prepared for that (hopefully near) future.

Comment: After AngularJS 1.9 would be 1.10; they're version numbers, not floats. But AngularJS is EOL, there won't be minor versions past 1.7.x (see https://blog.angular.io/stable-angularjs-and-long-term-support-7e077635ee9c).

Comment: Angular have never been good with version numbers, so I would not be surprised if they consider it a float :), anyway it was just a joke about the 2 creating this mess.

Comment: Why not just use tag the main language/framework `[angular]` , it's version `[angular-x]` and then only the library name `[material]`. I would read such tags as *angular with version x and using the library material*. Or are there mutliple library versions per angular major version

Comment: @Lino that is more or less suggestion 1, with the difference of renaming [angular-material] to only [material], I'm not so sure this renaming is a good idea since [material] is a bit too generic to indicate the specific library [angular/material](https://github.com/angular/material2), only material would be probably better to use only for [Material Design](https://material.io/design/), true angular/material is built on this, but still angular/material is a specific lib.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Hm, I see the problem, then I would probably just go with suggestion **1**, seems like the appropriate approach

Comment: We should just ask the angular team to help us solve this madness.

Comment: just ignore the problem

Comment: I’ve been ignoring Angular for years, @Kevin. It hasn’t gone away yet. In fact, it seems to have… *multiplied*, which is the point of this question. You suggest we ignore it because it’s not a problem? Or impossible to solve? Or what?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem worth solving.

Comment: Somewhat unfortunate that high rep users, who should be at the forefront of solving the sites issues, are just nodding their head and saying that it is better to look away than to spend time on it.

Comment: To me, Angular dev, it's quite important to filter out AngularJS (version < 2) from Angular (2+) questions. When I stumble on a non-ignored question incorrectly tagged Angular instead of AngularJS, I prompty retag it. Also, Angular *material* is some specific nearly external library, and deserves its own tag.

Comment: This is much needed cleanup! I like the option 2, because it's seems more intuitive